# Hive shows less rows than HBase

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, hbase

I created a Hive table over a HBase data source and imported data (CSV file) from S3 into this table.  This is running on AWS EMR.

I've validated this with a handful of rows and it is fine.

However when I import a reasonable dataset (10 million rows), I get a disparity in the count that Hive gives me and what HBase gives me.

If I do a count in HBase I get a result of 10 million.

If I do a count in Hive I get a result of 9,932,183.

I have written a query to brute force compare the imported data with the source S3 data, but this takes a massive amount of time to execute even on a moderately large cluster.

In the meantime, looking for possibilities and ideas as to what could cause this disparity.

I should note that I would class myself as a noob in this department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably missing rows are inconsistent with the hive table schema.

Comment: why would they be present in HBase though?  They have the same schema, but is HBase more 'forgiving', i.e. it will happily accept the data in a mismatch format but Hive will exclude these?

Answer (score 0):

Vijay you are correct.

The source data had 67,817 rows where one of the columns was NULL.

This data was inserted successfully into HBASE.

However the Hive schema stated that this data was mapped to a BIGINT type, so Hive excluded the whole row as it didn't match the schema.